# How can I properly display this specific shape path in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

Firstly, I'm a beginner in JavaFX coding. Here, I'm actually trying to implement the Material Design checkbox as you can see right [here](https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/checkbox), and using the API's default `CheckBox` for testing, here's what I currently have:

*Overriding `CheckBox`'s shape:*

```
.check-box > .box > .mark {
  /* SVG path directly copied from the site. */
  -fx-shape: "M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59";
}
```

*Resulting to this:*

[image]

So basically, I just copied the SVG path used by the MD checkbox component from [here](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/checkboxes/#basic-usage) but it's not properly displayed as what the image above portrays in my case. All I knew is the basics about SVG paths but drawing such complicated paths like the one I'm referring above is difficult for me.

Now, my question is how can I fix this one? Thanks for all the answers.

---

## UPDATE

For others who were curious about what @Itai's provided shape path looks like, here it is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path given in `-fx-shape` is the shape of the region, and is implicitly closed (last point connected to first) - this explains the result you are seeing, where the top right corner is connected back to the top left to create a triangle.

You may be able to use this exact path using an `SVGPath` node, as in this question: [How to style a SVG using CSS in javaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35604436/how-to-style-a-svg-using-css-in-javafx-fxml)

Another possibility is to "transform" the path to the outline of the shape you want - by retracing the points in reverse order with slightly higher (or lower) Y values:

```
.check-box > .box > .mark {
    /* SVG path directly copied from the site. */
    -fx-shape: "M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59 22.79,1.59 8.1,16.28 1.73,9.91";
}
```

In this case I have subtracted 3 from the Y values of every point and repeated them in reverse order, so get the original shape, 3 pixels wide. Note that this very basic transformation doesn't simulate any "miter" or "joint" effect, but it works in a pinch.

Comment: I tried the `SVGPath` but the result is still the same. But anyways, I will be using your provided path so thank you very much for your answer.